# Does the inequality still hold if I invert both sides with cyclic sums?

Tags: inequality

For example if I invert both sides of

$$ \sum_{\sigma} \frac{x(x+2)}{2x^2 + 1} \geq 0$$

So that it becomes

$$\sum_{\sigma}\frac{2x^2+1}{x(x+2)} \leq 0$$

Will the inequality hold?

Comment: Skipping the unnecessary details, in effect you ask what can be said about ${1\over x}+{1\over y}+{1\over z}$ if $x+y+z\ge0$. The answer is: **nothing**.

Comment: What about this particular case @IvanNeretin?

Comment: Never mind I found the solution through a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Does $x\geq 0$ imply $\dfrac{1}{x}\leq 0$?